# Can't get SearchDialog to function in Mono for Android app

Tags: c#, android, search, mono, xamarin.android

I've spent far too long trying to get the SearchDialog to come up for an Android app I'm developing using Mono for Android. I'm hoping someone else might be able to take a look and tell me what I'm doing wrong.

I've been using the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#SearchableActivity) as well as [another StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8525415/search-dialog-in-mono-android) to guide me, but no luck.

The search button on the emulator doesn't appear to work (won't even light up on mouseover), but I'm able to press F5 and hit a breakpoint in my OnSearchRequested method. I attempted to look at SearchManager at runtime, but couldn't find any hints.

I'm attempting to get my launcher activity (Activity1) to use another activity (SearchableActivity). There is no implementation in SearchableActivity.cs apart from the standard OnCreate override.

Everything is in namespace "test1."

My resulting AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="G.Clients">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />
  <application android:label="Our Clients" android:name="mono.android.app.Application" android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:name="test1.SearchableActivity">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable" android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable" android:value="test1.SearchableActivity" />
    <activity android:label="Main" android:name="test1.Activity1">
      <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable" android:value="test1.SearchableActivity" />
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:label="Clients" android:name="test1.ClientListActivity" />
    <provider android:name="mono.MonoRuntimeProvider" android:exported="false" android:initOrder="2147483647" android:authorities="G.Clients.__mono_init__" />
    <receiver android:name="mono.android.Seppuku">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="mono.android.intent.action.SEPPUKU" />
        <category android:name="mono.android.intent.category.SEPPUKU.G.Clients" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
  </application>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

My searchable.xml (located in folder Resources/xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding=utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  android:label="search" android:hint="clients">
</searchable>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else stumbles on this, it appears I missed a sample project on the xamarin.com site: [SearchableDictionary](http://samples.xamarin.com/Details/Android/5e197185-b5a5-4d37-9f47-67ce6526a5b9)

I was able to make modifications to my own project based on this working sample.